# 504 Gateway Time-out error Keycloak with Microsoft SSO

Tags: azure, openshift, single-sign-on, keycloak

I am running a Node App that uses Keycloak for authentication. I added Microsoft as my Identity Provider. The authentication flow works sometimes, but sometimes it also gives me a `504 Gateway Time-out` error. I am not able to pinpoint the issue here and it seems to manifest in a non deterministic manner, which makes debugging it pretty painful. Maybe somebody can shine some light on the problem. Here is some information about my setup in Keycloak:

I am deploying Keycloak in an Openshift pod using the `jboss/keycloak:12.0.4` docker image. I configured the Identity Provider as an `OpenID Connect v1.0` instead of the `Microsoft` listed option. The reason for that is that the `Microsoft` option was giving me an error because my application does not support multiple tenants. I noticed that my `Authorization URL` and my `Token URL` use oauth2 v2.0 and the OpenID Protocol that Keycloak supports is v1.0, could this be the culprit?

Here are the settings I am using in my `OpenID Connect v1.0` Identity Provider:

| Setting | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Redirect URI | https://{myURL}/auth/realms/{myRealm}/broker/microsoft/endpoint |
| Display Name | Microsoft SSO |
| Enabled | True |
| Store Tokens | False |
| Store Tokens Readable | False |
| Trust Email | True |
| Account Linking Only | False |
| Hide on Login Page | False |
| GUI orderPage |  |
| First Login Flow | first broker login |
| Post Login Flow |  |
| Sync Mode | import |
| Authorization URL | [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{myTenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BmyTenantId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize) |
| Pass login_hint | False |
| Pass current locale | False |
| Token URL | [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{myTenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BmyTenantId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token) |
| Logout URL |  |
| Backchannel Logout | False |
| Disable User Info | False |
| User Info URL |  |
| Client Authentication | Client secret sent as post |
| Client ID | {myClientId} |
| Client Secret | **** |
| Issuer |  |
| Default Scopes | profile email |
| Prompt | unspecified |
| Accepts prompt=none forward from client | False |
| Validate Signatures | False |
| Allowed clock skew | 30 |
| Forwarded Query Parameters |  |

When I try to login in the Keycloak site I get a Timeout error like this:

[image]

Sometimes I get it directly in the Kecloak login site after clicking the "Login with Microsoft" button. Other times I do get redirected to the login.microsoftonline.com webpage, where I login with my credentials and it gets stuck in the last screen after asking if I want to stay signed in. And sometimes the flow works and I end up authenticated inside of my application...

Here ist the error response that I get after some time of waiting:

```
Request URL: https://{myURL}/auth/realms/{myRealm}/broker/microsoft/endpoint?code=0.AXMA7rFZoACDkkmxG1e0i4BPEZ2cuYMZnDRNtktAE1vudc9zAAA.AQABAAIAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7WevrbG5Onmk6dlEN-ouVhfpouPkxBHIMaTipydQjf5IPHzHiiF047jqUMeFyZsK2MS_SFivrQzEHsLKCwb1cxoqNflANN5M61kRmWAPl3aMaS-Ss2UyBjRWvDa6uWHm91RYglSSu5KYle1iuuGQy6lbCDylPxGvYuvg0-JYX607C416_BCPWv54T2OseM1FouKs9ZjWTtshbfMphilE7xoY6ELTOza12SitW3-d0XzTpQxBBI4hJYVq1SWMa6LlOPqrFnofmTdQxbzLJrzWgbvXPXD_Mq-y2MABWv1Vp4cC-BWQp7LAvgt5YM4qODrO16hhbRsIoVpGx8Fo4hdGHfz5gzYJSZ7l1JKVm0mPN3EUB36Bxu6nU5H_WEzQKnPgEuWM_XwF1FF3zCEC_T7OCFk8eclh_Ltkj4_6bbvIzq4fkhQHi5ip95JVZCf363JufQfpMwwXuEkBpoA7r_sJZf7eovktt_yF_TY2n6eg2Buhss86fRNplj6lJarUk1wfPg8UtQfIM03Q6ibOdFUbdXKlTNTzBtEXPE09Oq-k58lY54WEuc-6CoI0TVacj5uPAMchIiT9W5zh6Hngrch_JO3_AFY2y4AyZ5z4ztPdmNbI-H5SrTgL6su0B3AW-1ZaSbbtvt5IjuE_BsgDCyUcleELMoScxVTu209iqv1PSJGHm6zX0JLT314nNhv_vft-11mVzn5PnEUvMjnq-SIblkVBFJNo_aHuHZ6YKA5bkTJzRmJsgAA&state=bkT6WkO40z5T_nZmjgWjyr0Yrig9aubRO4tIWzw6FyE.XNF2CybyXuc.express-server&session_state=1406bf80-2d5a-4e76-a526-a68c92369bfd
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 504 Gateway Time-out
Remote Address: **.***.***.***:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: AUTH_SESSION_ID=0adf14f3-e2e7-45ad-81f0-41ba2ef14b00.fv-keycloak-dbs-7-zjzrr; AUTH_SESSION_ID_LEGACY=0adf14f3-e2e7-45ad-81f0-41ba2ef14b00.fv-keycloak-dbs-7-zjzrr; KC_RESTART=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJmYzk5ZmY2Yy01ZTYzLTRhZDYtOGQ1MS0zNjUzODc4ZTI3NWEifQ.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_c2hhcmVwb2ludE9uPWZhbHNlJmF1dGhfY2FsbGJhY2s9MSIsInN0YXRlIjoiYzE5MTZkNDMtNTRkYi00NjdiLWFkOTEtYTk1YThiZTkzYjA5In19.SUlsPCDZ3cOdhWYxGlyjw_5fE97VtVQ3m4JICGwEadE; f7ab773005f1250ab8c4988c6f4d7351=e1353a733014b755be89489617967322
Host: {myKeycloakHost}
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36
code: 0.AXMA7rFZoACDkkmxG1e0i4BPEZ2cuYMZnDRNtktAE1vudc9zAAA.AQABAAIAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7WevrbG5Onmk6dlEN-ouVhfpouPkxBHIMaTipydQjf5IPHzHiiF047jqUMeFyZsK2MS_SFivrQzEHsLKCwb1cxoqNflANN5M61kRmWAPl3aMaS-Ss2UyBjRWvDa6uWHm91RYglSSu5KYle1iuuGQy6lbCDylPxGvYuvg0-JYX607C416_BCPWv54T2OseM1FouKs9ZjWTtshbfMphilE7xoY6ELTOza12SitW3-d0XzTpQxBBI4hJYVq1SWMa6LlOPqrFnofmTdQxbzLJrzWgbvXPXD_Mq-y2MABWv1Vp4cC-BWQp7LAvgt5YM4qODrO16hhbRsIoVpGx8Fo4hdGHfz5gzYJSZ7l1JKVm0mPN3EUB36Bxu6nU5H_WEzQKnPgEuWM_XwF1FF3zCEC_T7OCFk8eclh_Ltkj4_6bbvIzq4fkhQHi5ip95JVZCf363JufQfpMwwXuEkBpoA7r_sJZf7eovktt_yF_TY2n6eg2Buhss86fRNplj6lJarUk1wfPg8UtQfIM03Q6ibOdFUbdXKlTNTzBtEXPE09Oq-k58lY54WEuc-6CoI0TVacj5uPAMchIiT9W5zh6Hngrch_JO3_AFY2y4AyZ5z4ztPdmNbI-H5SrTgL6su0B3AW-1ZaSbbtvt5IjuE_BsgDCyUcleELMoScxVTu209iqv1PSJGHm6zX0JLT314nNhv_vft-11mVzn5PnEUvMjnq-SIblkVBFJNo_aHuHZ6YKA5bkTJzRmJsgAA
state: bkT6WkO40z5T_nZmjgWjyr0Yrig9aubRO4tIWzw6FyE.XNF2CybyXuc.express-server
session_state: 1406bf80-2d5a-4e76-a526-a68c92369bfd
```

And here ist the same response when it does succeed and I end up logged in in my application:

```
Request URL: https://{myURL}/auth/realms/{myRealm}/broker/microsoft/endpoint?code=0.AXMA7rFZoACDkkmxG1e0i4BPEZ2cuYMZnDRNtktAE1vudc9zAAA.AQABAAIAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7Wevr54rmOYKEJxCvOnbTf08bIkW6-wYHMPW02S7p1GH83rt_I4HcFoQWc-UTr6E59PQtmKVvhJwPVOtCaloEntwSxyUOjU-ioLUqabuXrOgCK9z0YCAZfPt0i3en6yRq5_8cXTwb3mw_tdC4r72UhRy0-5lZtw0QK6nIBt5csBVe2aecbuUqSgujb342mI2yncyCtTzEDyHK68705BUc5CfZ_G1KrKY4XhOT2gJntasYNZ8W1cEaiRUINe3lJPChcdFSsK1_cXbt8cpcA-ATZII31pYDIj4naXf3TE03OazX_rbTAY9Wv9FemrDD81zoPpWvw-_0C10ZSyVKkiuDpijfLbXPds1PLXqO5_UHVi-L0PTo7Ol_mvy89wX7R7nzXcxQhFJ9N4tBk7_xsnJb84ra2FohF8Fc3nUQlpHKpyVOBF8ZiHmSDbKNFiYwPlO8eGwYl7bDKGezpBGNNyTHQgdh_sUr_JRxo3hAH-KBN5jQbarSPYVcju7DzGbEqdCEjyz2WbNwSw9-iSfFDloUNtiVG_67ZNJTFfuLR3_JkIZi3oOkFnAJXioaRLvijvPFsIcAAf8gvK1GTVyB4Hjqsh4UGFu3zEydKCAfBc-adK8Hh_OBa0_aqNe3vxGXmHdXxwUoK1CRCWXJKGWudyryfsgAZFSSCpoBgGRfVXezW03cHPW3OnLz_yxXZNgsDBY1RxY9v_FG0H1Y3WUXZswQGZ-EFRsLzYlbs1h-xscOc5a8mtAgAA&state=ZuSmElb8DZVi2RfJqty-GXjEI6JTHhgDYsQIj3iLnR0.tXmQN28xbw8.express-server&session_state=e2530203-3269-4f2a-b08c-27955bed47d2
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: **.***.***.**:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 06 Apr 2021 11:52:29 GMT
Location: http://{myURL}/login?auth_callback=1&state=143f770b-8de8-4083-8dab-3124bd097b98&session_state=ca4e579e-e22f-4b53-b33b-3bbc161c3ace&code=ca8be1ac-2bcf-420d-be27-9c830d7d6c31.ca4e579e-e22f-4b53-b33b-3bbc161c3ace.960c20e3-4c92-4bba-afea-785097c6fc69
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy!"
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Set-Cookie: KEYCLOAK_LOCALE=; Version=1; Comment=Expiring cookie; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/auth/realms/fileverificator/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: KC_RESTART=; Version=1; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/auth/realms/fileverificator/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJmYzk5ZmY2Yy01ZTYzLTRhZDYtOGQ1MS0zNjUzODc4ZTI3NWEifQ.eyJleHAiOjE2MTc3NDU5NDksImlhdCI6MTYxNzcwOTk0OSwianRpIjoiNTU0YmU1ZTEtZTA5My00ZWMzLTk0MjQtNDljMjhiMmIzYzlmIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9kYnMtZnYta2V5Y2xvYWstZmlsZXZlcmlmaWNhdG9yLmJlcmxpbi5kYmNzLmRiLmRlL2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL2ZpbGV2ZXJpZmljYXRvciIsInN1YiI6IjE2ZGZhN2UzLTQ1ZmMtNDNkZi05MjA1LTM5NTM4ZGRmY2M5MyIsInR5cCI6IlNlcmlhbGl6ZWQtSUQiLCJzZXNzaW9uX3N0YXRlIjoiY2E0ZTU3OWUtZTIyZi00YjUzLWIzM2ItM2JiYzE2MWMzYWNlIiwic3RhdGVfY2hlY2tlciI6IjlMZTV0Vy1WVVRGbUJOQ1B3TG1lN3NMWlMwd1piQnVKcEo0QXlGa1oyVVEifQ.d0cKuvmJcQp9dkyord6jzIIRqq9dHVoT5J-gOoOS3hU; Version=1; Path=/auth/realms/{myRealm}/; SameSite=None; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY_LEGACY=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJmYzk5ZmY2Yy01ZTYzLTRhZDYtOGQ1MS0zNjUzODc4ZTI3NWEifQ.eyJleHAiOjE2MTc3NDU5NDksImlhdCI6MTYxNzcwOTk0OSwianRpIjoiNTU0YmU1ZTEtZTA5My00ZWMzLTk0MjQtNDljMjhiMmIzYzlmIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9kYnMtZnYta2V5Y2xvYWstZmlsZXZlcmlmaWNhdG9yLmJlcmxpbi5kYmNzLmRiLmRlL2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL2ZpbGV2ZXJpZmljYXRvciIsInN1YiI6IjE2ZGZhN2UzLTQ1ZmMtNDNkZi05MjA1LTM5NTM4ZGRmY2M5MyIsInR5cCI6IlNlcmlhbGl6ZWQtSUQiLCJzZXNzaW9uX3N0YXRlIjoiY2E0ZTU3OWUtZTIyZi00YjUzLWIzM2ItM2JiYzE2MWMzYWNlIiwic3RhdGVfY2hlY2tlciI6IjlMZTV0Vy1WVVRGbUJOQ1B3TG1lN3NMWlMwd1piQnVKcEo0QXlGa1oyVVEifQ.d0cKuvmJcQp9dkyord6jzIIRqq9dHVoT5J-gOoOS3hU; Version=1; Path=/auth/realms/fileverificator/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: KEYCLOAK_SESSION=fileverificator/16dfa7e3-45fc-43df-9205-39538ddfcc93/ca4e579e-e22f-4b53-b33b-3bbc161c3ace; Version=1; Expires=Tue, 06-Apr-2021 21:52:29 GMT; Max-Age=36000; Path=/auth/realms/fileverificator/; SameSite=None; Secure
Set-Cookie: KEYCLOAK_SESSION_LEGACY=fileverificator/16dfa7e3-45fc-43df-9205-39538ddfcc93/ca4e579e-e22f-4b53-b33b-3bbc161c3ace; Version=1; Expires=Tue, 06-Apr-2021 21:52:29 GMT; Max-Age=36000; Path=/auth/realms/fileverificator/
Set-Cookie: KEYCLOAK_REMEMBER_ME=; Version=1; Comment=Expiring cookie; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/auth/realms/fileverificator/; HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: AUTH_SESSION_ID=ca4e579e-e22f-4b53-b33b-3bbc161c3ace.fv-keycloak-dbs-7-zjzrr; AUTH_SESSION_ID_LEGACY=ca4e579e-e22f-4b53-b33b-3bbc161c3ace.fv-keycloak-dbs-7-zjzrr; KC_RESTART=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJmYzk5ZmY2Yy01ZTYzLTRhZDYtOGQ1MS0zNjUzODc4ZTI3NWEifQ.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_c2hhcmVwb2ludE9uPWZhbHNlJmF1dGhfY2FsbGJhY2s9MSIsInN0YXRlIjoiMTQzZjc3MGItOGRlOC00MDgzLThkYWItMzEyNGJkMDk3Yjk4In19.L7zIusN60YSeALEIPEUNdchas_9ey-ZDqtWXjgynC5Q; f7ab773005f1250ab8c4988c6f4d7351=e1353a733014b755be89489617967322
Host: {myKeycloakHost}
Referer: https://login.microsoftonline.com/
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36
code: 0.AXMA7rFZoACDkkmxG1e0i4BPEZ2cuYMZnDRNtktAE1vudc9zAAA.AQABAAIAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7Wevr54rmOYKEJxCvOnbTf08bIkW6-wYHMPW02S7p1GH83rt_I4HcFoQWc-UTr6E59PQtmKVvhJwPVOtCaloEntwSxyUOjU-ioLUqabuXrOgCK9z0YCAZfPt0i3en6yRq5_8cXTwb3mw_tdC4r72UhRy0-5lZtw0QK6nIBt5csBVe2aecbuUqSgujb342mI2yncyCtTzEDyHK68705BUc5CfZ_G1KrKY4XhOT2gJntasYNZ8W1cEaiRUINe3lJPChcdFSsK1_cXbt8cpcA-ATZII31pYDIj4naXf3TE03OazX_rbTAY9Wv9FemrDD81zoPpWvw-_0C10ZSyVKkiuDpijfLbXPds1PLXqO5_UHVi-L0PTo7Ol_mvy89wX7R7nzXcxQhFJ9N4tBk7_xsnJb84ra2FohF8Fc3nUQlpHKpyVOBF8ZiHmSDbKNFiYwPlO8eGwYl7bDKGezpBGNNyTHQgdh_sUr_JRxo3hAH-KBN5jQbarSPYVcju7DzGbEqdCEjyz2WbNwSw9-iSfFDloUNtiVG_67ZNJTFfuLR3_JkIZi3oOkFnAJXioaRLvijvPFsIcAAf8gvK1GTVyB4Hjqsh4UGFu3zEydKCAfBc-adK8Hh_OBa0_aqNe3vxGXmHdXxwUoK1CRCWXJKGWudyryfsgAZFSSCpoBgGRfVXezW03cHPW3OnLz_yxXZNgsDBY1RxY9v_FG0H1Y3WUXZswQGZ-EFRsLzYlbs1h-xscOc5a8mtAgAA
state: ZuSmElb8DZVi2RfJqty-GXjEI6JTHhgDYsQIj3iLnR0.tXmQN28xbw8.express-server
session_state: e2530203-3269-4f2a-b08c-27955bed47d2
```

Any ideas on what could be causing the issue? As I said it does work sometimes, so I am really curious why this behaviour occurs.

Comment: I'm having the same issue... but only in the prod environment, while my test environment for some reason works fine... did you find out what the issue was?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on self-managed and also have the [same issue with Keycloak 13.0.1](https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/issues/694). It should work if you do a port forward but that's not ideal...